# Compute and return distance in EF 6 / LINQ to Entities / DbGeography?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

Using **.NET 4.5.1** and **Entity Framework 6.0.2**, I've got something like the entities and query below.

Basically I am selecting a `new` entity and mashing the `Distance` into it, when I'd rather query a `Person` and have `Distance` embedded in that person's `Location` entity.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [...]

    public virtual ICollection<PersonLocation> PersonLocations { get; private set;}
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Geocode { get; set; }
    // ... I want calculated Distance right here 
}

public class PersonLocation
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptingNewClients { get; set; }
    public Hours Hours { get; set; }
    [...]

    public virtual Person Person { get; private set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; private set; }
}
```

Currently I have a query like this, where `_geo` is a `DbGeography` set to the desired search location and `radius` is an `int = 15`:

```
IQueryable<PersonWithDistance> results =
    from pl in db.PersonLocations
    let distance = pl.Location.Geocode.Distance(_geo)
    where pl.Location.Geocode.IsEmpty == false
    where distance <= radius * 1609.344
    orderby distance
    select new { Person = pl.Person, Distance = Math.Round((double)(distance / 1609.344), 1) };
```

What I'd like instead is to have `Distance` added to each `Location` entity and just select the `Person` entity in the query.

Is there a way to do this?  Should I be going a different route altogether?

Comment: OT: You should avoid magic numbers. You might want to set up a constant somewhere that defines the number of metres in a mile. e.g. `const double metresInMile = 1609.344` so that the code is more easily readable by people who may not know what this arbitrary looking number means.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Geocode { get; set; }

    public double? Distance { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext setup, so that EF ignores the column as it relates to the database:

```
Ignore(x => x.Distance);
```

The search query becomes:

```
var results = (from pl in db.PersonLocations
                let distance = pl.Location.Geocode.Distance(_geo)
                where pl.Location.Geocode.IsEmpty == false
                where distance <= radius * 1609.344
                select pl.Person).Distinct();
```

And finally:

```
var personsWithDistance = results.ToList();

foreach (Person p in personsWithDistance)
{
    var pls = p.PersonLocations;

    foreach (PersonLocation pl in pls)
    {
        if (pl.Location.Geocode != null)
            pl.Location.Distance = Math.Round((double)(pl.Location.Geocode.Distance(_geo) / 1609.344), 1);
        else
            pl.Location.Distance = null;
    }
}

// order by distance
personsWithDistance = personsWithDistance.OrderBy(r => r.PersonLocations.FirstOrDefault().Location.Distance).ToList();

return personsWithDistance;
```

Essentially I created a fake column/property in the `Location` entity and told the DbContext to ignore it.  I query for the resultset I want and then manually update the property and return the results.

It doesn't feel right somehow, but it works.